# Angularjs ng-repeat over array of array of objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use ng-repeat over this array of array of objects, but I am unable to get to display the correct name-value pairs.

```
var names = [
[{name: "Name 1", age: 25}, {name: "Name 2", age: 20}],
[{name: "Name 3", age: 50}, {name: "Name 4", age: 40}],
[{name: "Name 5", age: 20}, {name: "Name 6", age: 40}]
];
```

This works to display the entire array of array of objects:

```
<p ng-repeat="name in names"></p>
```

But the following to display the name doesn't:

```
<p ng-repeat="name in names">
    <p ng-repeat="n in name">
        {{n.name}}
    </p>
</p>
```

I know I am for sure missing something simple.

Comment: this should work, can you create a plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like nested **p** tag causes ng-repeat messes up beginning/ending tag

If you change the inside **p** tag to **span** or **div**, it works:

```
<p ng-repeat="name in names">        
    <span ng-repeat="n in name">
        {{n.name}}
    </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your multi array to use a array of objects with an array of items like below:

```
var names = [
{items:[{name: "Name 1", age: 25}, {name: "Name 2", age: 20}]},
{items:[{name: "Name 3", age: 50}, {name: "Name 4", age: 40}]},
{items:[{name: "Name 5", age: 20}, {name: "Name 6", age: 40}]}
];

<p ng-repeat="name in names">
    <p ng-repeat="n in name.items">
        {{n.name}}
    </p>
</p>
```

Comment: But i fail to understand why his code does not work?